# Ratio of Uniforms simulation

Tags: simulation, computational-statistics

I am new to simulation methods and am currently learning about the ratio of uniforms method. The problem I am working on is to use the ratio-of-uniform method to create a random number generator in `R` for a probability density:

$$p(x) \sim \bigg( 1+\frac{x^2}{v} \bigg)^{-(v+1)/2}.$$

The method is as follows.  Define the set:

$$C_h \equiv \Bigg\{ (u,v) \Bigg| 0 \leq u \le \sqrt{\frac{hv}{u}} \Bigg\}.$$

Now perform the following steps:

1. Generate $u_1,u_2 \sim \text{IID U}(0,1)$;
2. Let $u = a u_1$ and $v = b_- + (b_+-b_-) u_2$;
3. If $(u,v) \in C_h$ return $v/u$.

I understand how to use the density function and go about the simulation method and code it up in `R`, but the one part I am currently stuck on is how do we determine what $a$, $b_-$, and $b_+$ are to go from $u_1, u_2$ to $(u,v)$?

Comment: Welcome to cross validated. The typical way that $a$, $b_{-}$, and $b_{+}$ are determined are by solving: $a=sup_x \sqrt{f(X)}$, $b_{+}=sup_x x\sqrt{f(x)}$ and for $b_{-}$ replace the $sup$ from $b_{+}$ with and $inf$. You are solving for extremal $x$ in these 3 equations and then putting the found $x$ values (one for each equation) into the respective equation for these points. At least if you want *optimal* bounds, if you use constants larger than these you'd just be doing more draws of $u_1$, $u_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I described the approach in a comment above but I'll explicitly do some of the calculations.

The intuition is that $b_{-}$ and $b_{+}$ are lower and upper bounds of a rectangle defined by $U_1, U_2 \sim U(0,1)$ once rescaled. The other sides of the rectangle has height $a$.

To find the values you need to determine $x$ such that $a=sup_x \sqrt{f(x)}$. To do this you can take logarithms and then a derivative and set equal to 0 and solve resulting equation for $x$. Similar approaches can be done for $b_{+}=sup_x x\sqrt{f(x)}$, and $b_{-}=inf_x x\sqrt{f(x)}$.

Worked example for $a$:

$$
\text{log}(f(x)) = -\frac{\nu+1}{4}\left[\text{log}(\nu^2+x^2) - \text{log}(\nu^2)\right],
$$
taking derivative w.r.t. $x$ and equating with zero after some rearranging terms gives,

$$
-\frac{x(\nu+1)}{\nu^2+x^2} = 0.
$$

Which can simplify to $x(\nu+1) =0$ which is true for $x=0$ or $\nu=-1$ but $\nu \geq 1$ as this is the degrees of freedom in a t distribution so $x=0$. Now evaluate
$\sqrt{f(0)}$ to determine the value is $1$. You can verify that $x=0$ is a $supremum$.

Similar but lengthy calculations can be done for $b_{+}$ and $b_{-}$ to determine $x$ values and then evaluated in the respective sup/inf formulae.

This process is very rote but keep in mind that the random variable is being mapped from $x$ space to $(u(x), v(x))$ space via the mapping
$u(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$ and $v(x) = x\sqrt{f(x)}$, for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

The $inf$ and $sup$ conditions used are to ensure the ***minimal*** bounding rectangle is used in $(u,v)$ space which gives an ***optimal*** rejection constant.

Comment: Thank you, this all makes sense. Not related to the question, but curious, if you don't solve these to get the optimal rejection constant, is the only consequence that you will reject more random draws, or would it have an effect usefulness of the simulations as well?

Comment: @Chris if you choose values ***smaller*** then you would get incorrect results. If you choose values larger than the optimal bounding constants then the consequence is longer runtimes. If the constants are ***very*** large you might be waiting a very long time.